# Div height transition when children visibility change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height

```
<div id='parent'>
    <div class='children'></div>
    <div class='children'></div>
    <div class='children'></div>
    <div class='children'></div>
</div>
```

Children divs are displayed or hidden programmatically what changes the height of the parent element. How can I animate the change of `#parent`'s height? I tried with css transition property but it didn't work.

Comment: If this question is answered, then please feel free to accept the best suited answer.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `.hide()` and `.show()` use `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` animation which will give a nice effect instead of that shaky effect.

**Edit:** Added >> [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/phxEP/1/) <<

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id='parent'>
    <div class='children'></div>
    <div class='children'></div>
    <div class='children'></div>
    <div class='children'></div>
</div>

// suppose hiding last .children
$('.children:last').hide(0, function() {
  var ph = $(this).parent().height(),
      ch = $(this).height();
  $(this).parent().animate({
     height: ph-ch
  });
})
```

or simply like @Vege mentioned:

```
$('.children:last').hide();
```